# DBpedia dbo:height property and its value

Tags: ontology, dbpedia, knowledge-graph, opendata

Hello I just can't anywhere find what height (μ) means in DBpedia.

For example [LeBron James](https://dbpedia.org/page/LeBron_James) has `dbo:weight 113400.000000 (xsd:double)` and when I click on `dbo:weight` it is labeled as `weight (g)`. So weight is in grams.

But for [height](https://dbpedia.org/ontology/height): `dbo:height  2.057400 (xsd:double)` when I click on `dbo:height` there is label `height (μ)`. What does it mean ? I can see that the height is in meters, but does it mean that every height is in meters ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: If you ask me, it's a mistake or bug - these happen. It appears to be [the greek symbol abbreviation for the metre](https://github.com/dbpedia/extraction-framework/blob/284bafc3785251a6e918b49ac1ab5c6417e87807/core/src/main/scala/org/dbpedia/extraction/ontology/OntologyDatatypes.scala#L372). Why dbpedia chose to show that `µ` instead of `m` I cannot tell.